# Typings.json valid JSON format or documentation?

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework, typescript-typings

I can't find in Internet a documentation on typings.json so there is no way to validate if a typings.json is correct or read what is the exact usage of each property. Is there a place where a full documentation on typings.json format and supported properties can be found ?

For example after installing Phaser it comes with its own `\node_modules\phaser\typescript` folder and with `typings.json` inside it and bunch of `*.d.ts` files inside the folder. When I build my application I get this error from the TypeScript compiler so it looks like the typings.json has some problem but there is no documentation to be found on the typings.json format.

```
.../node_modules/phaser/typescript/typings.json(2,11): error TS1005: ';' expected.
.../node_modules/phaser/typescript/typings.json(3,11): error TS1005: ';' expected.
.../node_modules/phaser/typescript/typings.json(4,12): error TS1005: ';' expected.
.../node_modules/phaser/typescript/typings.json(5,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
```

Here is `\node_modules\phaser\typescript\typings.json` content:

```
{
    "name": "phaser",
    "main": "phaser.comments.d.ts",
    "files": ["pixi.comments.d.ts", "p2.d.ts"],
    "global": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's docs from typescriptlang org:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/writing-declaration-files.html

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

at bottom of page above is link to schema:

http://json.schemastore.org/tsconfig

Sorry, should have made this more clear. Try excluding the folders that contain the .ts files, using tsconfig.json:

```
"exclude": [
   "node_modules",
]
```